# Iterate over plist and set value per key

Tags: common-lisp, elisp

How can I iterate over a plist, prompt for each key a value and fill in said value into the plist?

I have 'the skeleton' of a list of properties for my projects

```lisp
(defconst project-properties
  '(:number nil
    :place nil
    :location nil))
```

I copy this list and fill in the values so I keep a skeleton list and have the filled in list to process it further.

I managed to do it for an alist, but am unable to change the functionality to let it work with plists.

```lisp
(defun project-prompt-properties-alist ()
  "Prompt for project properties and return them"
  (let ((properties (copy-alist project-properties)))
    (cl-loop for (prop . val) in properties
             do (setf (alist-get prop properties) (read-string (format "Geef %s: " prop))))
    properties))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Common Lisp and Elisp allow you to loop over a list using `on` which iterates on successive tails of the list, instead of `in` which iterates on successive elements of the list. For example:

```
CL-USER> (loop for tail on project-properties
               do (format t "~A~%" tail))
(NUMBER NIL PLACE NIL LOCATION NIL)
(NIL PLACE NIL LOCATION NIL)
(PLACE NIL LOCATION NIL)
(NIL LOCATION NIL)
(LOCATION NIL)
(NIL)
```

You can further use the `by` keyword to reduce the input list by two elements instead of one on each iteration:

```
CL-USER> (loop for tail on project-properties by #'cddr
               do (format t "~A~%" tail))
(NUMBER NIL PLACE NIL LOCATION NIL)
(PLACE NIL LOCATION NIL)
(LOCATION NIL)
```

You can use destructuring to take the first two elements of each tail:

```
CL-USER> (loop for (prop val) on project-properties by #'cddr
               do (format t "~A -> ~A~%" prop val))
NUMBER -> NIL
PLACE -> NIL
LOCATION -> NIL
```

These features work the same in Elisp. You should be able to write `project-prompt-properties-plist` for Elisp like this:

```
(defun project-prompt-properties-plist ()
  "Prompt for project properties and return them"
  (let ((properties (copy-sequence project-properties)))
    (cl-loop for (prop val) on properties by #'cddr
             do (plist-put properties prop (read-string (format "Geef %s: " prop))))
    properties))
```

Comment: Thanks for the eleborate breakdown on how to do this. Very informative.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collect user input for a list of properties, you can use that list directly to build the plist:

```lisp
(loop :for property :in '(:number :place :location)
      :collect property
      :collect (read-query-whatever property))
```

or the alist:

```lisp
(loop :for property :in '(:number :place :location)
      :collect (cons property
                     (read-query-whatever property)))
```

If you want to update properties that the user might want to leave unchanged, then you can also go over the given plist as you showed with the skeleton idea:

```lisp
(loop :for (property value) :on '(:number 23 :place nil :location "moon") :by #'cddr
      :collect property
      :collect (read-query-whatever property value))
```

or the same with an alist:

```lisp
(loop :for (property . value) :in '((:number . 23) (:place . nil) (:location "moon"))
      :collect (cons property
                     (read-query-whatever property value)))
```

These all build a new list step by step, instead of first copying and then updating it.